# using image alt content as lightbox image description content, change html src using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

My generated html source is as follows

```
<a href="/images/somePhoto.png" target="_blank">
   <img src="/img/somePhoto.png" alt="Image description text" width="286" height="171" />
</a>
```

I want to display image alt content in image popup window as image description(lightbox).
Bellow is part of generated html on lightbox popup window

```
<div class="lb-details">
<span class="lb-caption" style="display: none;"></span>
<span class="lb-number" style="display: none;"></span>
</div>
```

How to change this line 
`<span class="lb-caption" style="display: none;"></span>` to

```
<span class="lb-caption" style="display: inline;">ALT IMAGE CONTENT</span>
```

on dom ready using js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On DOM ready, Use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for changing its display property and [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for adding text to it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lbcaption = $('.lb-caption');
    lbcaption.css('display', 'inline');
    lbcaption.text($('img').attr('alt')); 
    //Works for the code posted in the question, 
    //but the selector for the image needs to be a class or an id.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I should be using dynamic image alt value, from image which has target="_blank"

Comment: @user2783193 ok.. does the image has a class or a unique ID or something? or is it just the `target=_blank`?

Comment: @user2783193 I updated my answer. But keep in my mind that if there are multiple images in your DOM you'll have to rewrite your image selector properly.